# Histogram For Non-Numerical Data

Tags: histograms

I have a non-numerical data, let say

```
data = Table[RandomChoice[{0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1} -> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}], {500}];
```

and i want to make a histogram for this data. My solution so far

```
datanew = data;
label = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[data];
Do[datanew = ReplaceAll[datanew, label[[i]] -> i], {i, 1, Length[label]}]
Histogram[datanew, Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, ChartLabels -> {None, Placed[label, Below]}]
```

Is there any better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Please post code to show what you want and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tallydata = SortBy[Tally[data], First];
BarChart[tallydata[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> (tallydata[[All, 1]])]
```

[image]