# How to make an Histogram where the data are strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, histograms, numerical-value

`Histogram[{3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}]` works great to give you an histogram in which mathematica counts the occurence of each number and makes the plot. Is there a variant for non-numeric data? Say I want to count and make an histogram on strings

`Histogram[{"a", "a", "b", "c"}]`

or even more general

`Histogram[{a, a, b, c}]`

where `a`,`b`, and `c` are (so far unassigned) symbols.

Is there a way to get this histogram from built-in functions?

Comment: `BarChart[#[[2]], ChartLabels -> #[[1]]] &@
 Transpose@Sort@Tally@{a, a, b, c}` ?

Comment: Duplicate http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34128/10397

Comment: Yet another possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96074/12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BarChart[Counts[{"a", "a", "b", "c"}], ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

By using `Counts` instead of `Tally`, we get an `Association` that `BarChart` knows how to handle automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Block[{t = Tally[{"a", "a", "b", "c"}]},
 BarChart[t[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> t[[All, 1]]
  ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]